# How can I add my own dropDown (<select>...</select> from widget) to CKEditor?

Tags: yii2, ckeditor

I have widget like this

```
<select><option value="link_to_mypage"> My Page </option> <select/>
```

I want to put this dropdown in CKEditor. If I choose item, it must put link like this:

```
<a href="link_to_mypage">My Page</a>
```

Is it possible?

Comment: do you want add option in ckeditor??

Comment: Yes. I want add dropdown in ckeditor